# AWS Lambda ssl/tls between rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I currently have a lambda function which communicates with an aws aurora postgres cluster. Given the nature of the application I need to ensure that the inflight communication is encrypted. We are using IAM database authentication and in the [RDS aurora the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) it states:

> *IAM database authentication provides the following benefits: Network traffic to and from the database is encrypted using Secure Socket
> Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS)*

Though there is little further explanation (that I can find) of how this works in the context of a lambda function i.e. how does the lambda verify that it trusts the issuer, or Certificate Authority, of the SSL certificate it receives. **NB** I have set the `rds.force_ssl` to `1` (true) to verify communication is indeed SSL/TLS and the application still functions normally.

The documentation goes onto link to another page [Using SSL/TLS to encrypt a connection to a DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) where it states:

> *SSL/TLS connections provide one layer of security by encrypting data that moves between your client and a DB cluster. Using a server
> certificate provides an extra layer of security by validating that the
> connection is being made to an Amazon Aurora DB cluster.*

What is meant by the server certificate I'm a little unsure about here - i.e. is that what the client uses to verify that it trusts the issuer of the cert it receives during the initial handshake?